# How stringfy list of values

Tags: json, typescript, angular6

I am trying to stringfy the response from Rest API.
The response which is getting from API is

```
[{ID: 1, Name: test, Values: "{uname: test, age: 24}"},{ID: 2, Name: test1, Values: "{uname: test1, age: 25}"}] 

 value: string[] = [];
 this.http.get('/api/test/' + id).subscribe(result => {        
      const res = result.json();
 });
```

**storing values in a string array**

```
 for (let result of res) {
    this.value.push(result.Values);
 }

 const string = JSON.stringify(this.value);
```

Expecting Result

```
[{"uname": "test", "age": "24"},{"uname": "test1", "age": "25"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map function` to get Values field

And this regex to correct JSON format

```
correctJson = badJson.replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');
```

Updated:
I update regex for add quote for both key and value object string.

```
correctedJson = badJson.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+): ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g, "\"$1\":\"$2\"")
```

It show your expected value.

```js
var obj = [{ID: 1, Name: 'test', Values: "{uname: test, age: 24}"},{ID: 2, Name: 'test1', Values: "{uname: test1, age: 25}"}];

var testobj = obj.map(c=>c.Values.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+): ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g, "\"$1\":\"$2\""));

console.log(JSON.stringify(testobj));
```

Comment: the array is coming as string like ["{"uname": "test", "age": "24"}","{"uname": "test1", "age": "25"}"] so i am unable perform iteration